# Array to single string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having an issue which I can't seem to solve. I have an array which I need to convert to an single string. The elements need to be put underneath each other.

```
sample_array = ['a','b','c','d','e']
```

desired output:

```
sample_array = "a
b
c
d
e"
```

I thought I could do this with a 'heredoc', but I can only get the elements behind each other inline. This is unfortunately not what I need. Anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edit for edit question**

In a single line, you can use inject:

```
sample_array = ['a','b','c','d','e']
puts sample_array.inject(""){|conc,x| conc + "\n" + x }

=> "a b c d e"
```

that will fold the array recursively and adding a line between chars